# Any free services like SauceLabs Cloud where i can run my selenium code on different browsers and devices?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was googling on any free services like  SauceLabs Cloud and i could not found any of the free services.
All are paid services or trials.
So is some one using any free services like SauceLabs Cloud where i can run my selenium code on different browsers and devices?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the list of some cloud base service the I am not sure which is free but I am sure there will be some trial period for these services.

> - AWS Device Farm
> - Firebase Test Lab for Android
> - Xamarin Test Cloud(Prefer paid one)
> - Kobiton
> - Perfecto
> - Experitest
> - Bitbar(free trial)
> - Geny Motion (free trial)

Comment: Thanks , let me try.But according to my experience im sure most of them are trials

Comment: as @Peter Masiar said, there is nothing like free. the only thing you can have the trial version of it & if you like it then you can go for the paid version.

Comment: And free test version is there ONLY because they don't want to pay anyone to train you and make the sale - you learn it on your own time and budget, saving them the sales expert to configure and sell to you. Even the "free " version is not really free, because, as you can guess now, TANSTAAFL :-) Providing free version is CHEAPER than providing sales expert.

Answer (score 4):

[There ain't no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) also known as TANSTAAFL.

Somebody needs to pay for the servers and salaries for people managing them. For all "free" services you use (gmail, facebook, etc), **you are not user - you are the product**. Companies provide you with **free services, so they can sell your info** (and anything you can glean about you, your interests, hobbies, friends etc, from how you use their services) to advertisers and whoever pays for it for whatever reason.

Automated tests do not care about the ads, so so their "attention" cannot be monetized. Just the opposite is true, companies providing "free" services spend effort to make sure that their customers are real humans, not robots - see [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

Answer (score 0):

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) - Paid one but providing the Free trail.